# Spring Boot WebSocket conflicts with SpringDoc Swagger UI: "Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket"

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, spring-websocket, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a Spring Boot application that uses WebSockets. I also want to expose Swagger UI using SpringDoc OpenAPI, but I'm running into an error.

When I try to access Swagger UI on `/swagger-ui/index.html/`, I get an error message that says "Can 'Upgrade' only to 'WebSocket'." It seems like the WebSockets endpoint is conflicting with the Swagger UI endpoint.

Here's my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new MyWebSocketHandler(), "/*").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDocConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("My API")
            .pathsToMatch("/api/**")
            .build();
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ws-demo</name>
    <description>ws-demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there a way to use WebSockets and SpringDoc OpenAPI together without running into this error and without having to change the websocket endpoint?

I've tried to set a custom URL for the Swagger UI in the Spring Doc configuration, using this property, but it didn't work as it just redirects to `/swagger-ui/index.html`:

`springdoc.swagger-ui.path=`

Answer (score 0):

Because websocket is `ws://` and swagger used `http://`